Python ARP device discovery - Broadcast message and tally results
I am hoping to approach a device discovery (LAN) problem. A manufacturer tool that we currently use sends an ARP broadcast packet on a specific port out to the LAN. Any devices listening on that port that understand the message reply with an UDP response on the same port to the originating broadcaster. The received UDP packets contain some basic device information that then allows for a script to perform further actions on them. The process looks like this:
Broadcaster --> ARP Broadcast --> Device 'Hears' --> Device Responds to Broadcaster with UDP packet
Now to the question itself: Can anyone point me to a suitable resource or provide some example code (Python 3) that can achieve the following for the example above

ARP Broadcast to LAN
Listen for UDP on specific port (can be multiple devices responding)
ARP Ping to 'set' the IP4 details of a specific device by MAC address

Any good reference on ARP messages in Python 3 would be greatly appreciated. I am finding the materials that turn up in searches to be somewhat confusing.
Any help or guidance greatly appreciated
The Frog
